# how can i change the EditText cursor knob color android (not the cursor color the knob)

Tags: android, android-edittext

[image: not the cursor color the knob color]I am trying to change my EditText cursor knob but failing to see it on a device, attached is my XML for this layout

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/new_text_edit_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/new_text_button_send"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:hint="@string/write_a_message"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_large"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
    android:inputType="text|textMultiLine|textCapSentences|textShortMessage"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor_glide_blue"
    android:lines="3"
    android:singleLine="false"/>
```

Comment: What do you mean by cursor knob??

Comment: use this android:textCursorDrawable="@color/color_dark_blue"

Comment: @Chandrakanth see this image

Comment: Ohh k in terms of android it is called as text selection handle :-) ..Check my answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the cursor selection handle in `EditText`

```
android:textSelectHandle="@drawable/handle_middle"
android:textSelectHandleLeft="@drawable/handle_left"
android:textSelectHandleRight="@drawable/handle_right"
```

Comment: What should be the the value of "@drawable/handle_middle"? I Just need to change the color as per show in the box in above image.

Comment: @YogGuru @drawable/xyz is the reference to the drawable image or resource file which presents in res/drawable folder.