# How to change the color of EditText cursor knob?

Tags: android

I want to change the color of EditText cursor knob

[image]

I have tried with Highlight color, textCursorDrawable

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30915729/6870450

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can i change the EditText cursor knob color android (not the cursor color the knob)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30915729/how-can-i-change-the-edittext-cursor-knob-color-android-not-the-cursor-color-th)

Answer (score 2):

`android:textCursorDrawable="@color/your_color"`